# Pointer being freed was not allocated, Abort trap: 6

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I'm not proficient in C programming so please excuse me if this isn't a strong question. In the following code, I can only allocate memory to `samplesVec`after obtaining the value of `nsamplepts`, but I need to return the vector `samplesVec` to the `main` for further use (not yet coded). However, I'm getting the following error:

**Error in Terminal Window**: 
ImportSweeps(3497,0x7fff7b129310) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fdaa0c03af8: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6

I'm using Mac OS X Mavericks with the gcc compiler. Thanks for any help.

**EDITED!!! AFTER VALUABLE INPUTS FROM COMMENTATORS, THE FOLLOWING REPRESENTS A SOLUTION TO THE ORIGINAL PROBLEM (WHICH IS NO LONGER AVAILABLE) **

The following code modification seemed to solve my original questions. Thanks for the valuable inputs everyone!

```
/* Header Files */
#define LIBAIFF_NOCOMPAT 1 // do not use LibAiff 2 API compatibility
#include <libaiff/libaiff.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/* Function Declarations */
void FileSearch(char*, char*, char*, char*, char*);
int32_t *ImportSweeps(char*);

/* Main */
int main()
{
char flag1[2] = "N";
char binname[20] = "bin1"; // dummy assignment
char buildfilename[40] = "SweepR";
char skeletonpath[100] = "/Users/.../Folder name/";
int k, len;

/* Find the sweep to be imported in the directory given by filepath */
FileSearch(skeletonpath, binname, buildfilename, skeletonpath, flag1);
if (strcmp(flag1,"Y")) {
    printf("No file found. End of program.\n");
} else {
    len = (int) strlen(skeletonpath);
    char *filepath = malloc(len);
    for (k = 0; k < len; k++) {
        filepath[k] = skeletonpath[k];
    }
    printf("File found! Filepath: %s\n", filepath);
    // Proceed to import sweep
    int32_t *sweepRfile = ImportSweeps(filepath);
    if (sweepRfile) {
        printf("Success!\n");
        // Do other things with sweepRfile
        free(sweepRfile);
    }
    free(filepath);
}
return 0;
}

/* Sub-Routines */
void FileSearch(char *dir, char *binname, char *buildfilename, char* filepath, char* flag1)
{
DIR *dp;
struct dirent *entry;
struct stat statbuf;
if((dp = opendir(dir)) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Cannot open directory: %s\n", dir);
    return;
}
chdir(dir);
while((entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
    lstat(entry->d_name, &statbuf);
    if(S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode)) {
        /* Found a directory, but ignore . and .. */
        if(strcmp(".",entry->d_name) == 0 || strcmp("..",entry->d_name) == 0)
            continue;
        strcpy(binname,entry->d_name);
        strcpy(buildfilename,"SweepR");
        /* Recurse at a new indent level */
        FileSearch(entry->d_name, binname, buildfilename, filepath, flag1);
    }
    else {
        sprintf(buildfilename, "%s%s.aiff", buildfilename, binname);
        if (strcmp(entry->d_name,buildfilename)) {
            strcpy(buildfilename,"SweepR");
        } else {
            sprintf(filepath, "%s%s/%s", filepath, binname, buildfilename);
            strcpy(flag1,"Y");
            break;
        }
    }
}
chdir("..");
closedir(dp);
}


int32_t *ImportSweeps(char *filepath)
{
char *filepathread = filepath;

/* Initialize files for importing */
AIFF_Ref fileref;

/* Intialize files for getting information about AIFF file */
uint64_t nSamples;
int32_t *samples = NULL;
int32_t *samplesVec = NULL;
int channels, bitsPerSample, segmentSize, ghost, nsamplepts;
double samplingRate;

/* Import Routine */
fileref = AIFF_OpenFile(filepathread, F_RDONLY) ;
if(fileref)
{
    // File opened successfully. Proceed.
    ghost = AIFF_GetAudioFormat(fileref, &nSamples, &channels, &samplingRate, &bitsPerSample, &segmentSize);
    if (ghost < 1)
    {
        printf("Error getting audio format.\n");
        AIFF_CloseFile(fileref); return (int32_t) 0;
    }
    nsamplepts = ((int) nSamples)*channels;
    samples = malloc(nsamplepts * sizeof(int32_t));
    samplesVec = malloc(nsamplepts * sizeof(int32_t));
    ghost = AIFF_ReadSamples32Bit(fileref, samples, nsamplepts);
    if (ghost) {
        for (int k = 0; k < nsamplepts; k++) {
            samplesVec[k] = *(samples+k);
        }
    }
    free(samples);
    AIFF_CloseFile(fileref);
}
return samplesVec;
}
```

Comment: What does `ImportSweeps` return? I only ask because this area of code looks suspect because of `sizeof(sweepRfile)/sizeof(int32_t)` which doesn't do what you think it does...

Comment: @John3136 ImportSweeps is supposed to return a large vector called samplesVec which contains data of type int32_t (defined in the libaiff library which I'm using).

Comment: That's ok then, but your length print out will be wrong (sizeof pointer / sizeof int) is probably 1.

Comment: @John3136 I get the same error even if I remove `sizeof(sweepRfile)/sizeof(int32_t)` from the code.

Comment: Yep, never said that was your problem, just that it is a problem. Youneed to isolate which free is causing the issue...

Comment: @John3136 What might be a way to do so? Thanks.

Comment: @John3136 The code for ImportSweeps was posted, so we know what it returns ... and it only contains one free, so it's already been isolated (we know it's the free in ImportSweeps because the error message says so).

Comment: Have you confirmed that the values you are getting for `channels` and `nSamples` are valid?

Comment: @rfernandes: Yes, `channels` and `nSamples` are valid.

Comment: When I got rid of `AIFF_CloseFile(fileref);`, the program worked but I don't think I'm supposed to do that based on the documentation of the libaiff library.

Answer (score 1):

So... as far as I can see... :-)

`samplesVec`, the return value of `ImportSweeps` is not initialized, if `fileref` is false. Automatic (== local) variables have no guarantees on its value if `samplesVec` are not explicitly initialized - in other words `samplesVec` could carry any address. If `samplesVec` is not `NULL` on luck (which on the other hand might be often the case), you try `free` a not allocated junk of memory, or by very bad luck an somewhere else allocated one.

If I'm correct with my guess you can easy fix this with:

```
int32_t *samples;
int32_t *samplesVec = NULL;
```

It is a good idea anyway to initialize any variable as soon as possible with some meaningful error or dummy value, if you not use it in the very next line. As pointers are horrible beasts, I always `NULL` them if I don't initialize them with a useful value on declaration.

Edit: Several minor small changes for a readable approximation to English. :-)

Comment: `samplesVec` is initialized. I checked it by printing its second value. I also gave a `printf("Test\n");` command after `free(samples)` and that was executed. But it looks like `samplesVec ` is not being returned to `main` because a `printf("Test\n");` command written after the line `int32_t *sweepRfile = ImportSweeps(filepath);` does NOT get executed.

Comment: I can't see any additional error in your code regarding the use of free, given you use `AIFF_OpenFile` correct. It is of course always possible that one of your library functions uses malloc()/free() and is buggy or got otherwise unexspected input.

Comment: I have identified something... Maybe you can help me identify the problem... In the main function, if I bypass the function `FileSearch(filepath, binname, buildfilename, filepath, flag1);`, change `char filepath[100] = "/Users/.../Foldername/";` to contain the address of the file that `FileSearch` normally finds (which I believe is correct - they have the same length) and set `char flag1[2] = "Y";` to the function `int32_t *ImportSweeps(char *filepath)`, then I need to include `AIFF_CloseFile(fileref);`. As long as the FileSearch function is bypassed, everything seems to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

If AIFF_OpenFile fails, ImportSweeps returns an undefined value because samplesVec wasn't initialized. If that value is non-NULL, main will try to free it. You can either initialize samplesVec = NULL, or you can reorganize the code as

```
fileref = AIFF_OpenFile(filepathread, F_RDONLY) ;
if(!fileref) {
{
    // print error message here
    return NULL;
}
// File opened successfully. Proceed.
...
```

There are people who will insist a functon that should only have one exit -- they are poorly informed and voicing a faulty dogma handed down from others who are likewise uninformed and dogmatic. The check for error and return above is known as a guard clause. The alternate style, of indenting every time a test succeeds, yields the arrow anti-pattern that is harder to read, harder to modify, and more error prone. See http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/ and http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrowAntiPattern for some discussion.

Comment: I tried your method to no avail. Echoing a previous comment of mine: `samplesVec` is initialized. I checked it by printing its second value. I also gave a `printf("Test\n");` command after `free(samples)` and that was executed. But it looks like `samplesVec ` is not being returned to `main` because a `printf("Test\n");` command written after the line `int32_t *sweepRfile = ImportSweeps(filepath);` does NOT get executed.

Comment: Um, samplesVec is **not** initialized; see, right there -- `int32_t *samples, *samplesVec;` no initializer. It gets *set*, but only if `fileref` isn't NULL. As for printf statements -- printf is buffered and you won't see the output if the program crashes. Never use it for debug output -- use fprintf(stderr, ...) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I just initialized `samplesVec` in my program (to NULL as suggested by Mark A.). So I have taken care of that but the original issue still remains.

Comment: When I got rid of `AIFF_CloseFile(fileref);`, the program worked but I don't think I'm supposed to do that based on the documentation of the libaiff library.

Comment: @Rahul You may have written beyond the bounds of malloced memory somewhere and confused malloc into thinking that some allocated piece wasn't.

Comment: I have identified something... Maybe you can help me identify the problem... In the main function, if I bypass the function `FileSearch(filepath, binname, buildfilename, filepath, flag1);`, change `char filepath[100] = "/Users/.../Foldername/";` to contain the address of the file that `FileSearch` normally finds (which I believe is correct - they have the same length) and set `char flag1[2] = "Y";` to the function `int32_t *ImportSweeps(char *filepath)`, then I need to include `AIFF_CloseFile(fileref);`. As long as the FileSearch function is bypassed, everything seems to work properly.